# Convergent series b^(2n+2) for b < 1

Tags: sequences-and-series

For which $b$ ($<1$) is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b^{2n+2} = 1
$$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\forall\, |b|<1\;\;,\;\;\;\sum_{n=0}^\infty b^{2n+2}=\frac{b^2}{1-b^2}$$